# AWS Appsync complex subscription arguments

Tags: ios, swift, aws-appsync, graphql-subscriptions

I'm currently working on an messaging app and want to create a global subscription just to demonstrate what I want to achieve Suppose there is a  mutation like sendMessage that contains senderId and Members just for example like :-

```
mutation sendMessage(senderId :String!,members:[String]){
    response
}
```

This mutation is used to send message to user the real example is different and complex so I'm asking with small example lets run a mutation with the following values like :-

```
mutation sendMessage(senderId :"A",members:["A","B","C"]){
    response
}
```

My question - Is it possible to get the subscription only when the members contain "B" in members array something like this :-

```
subscribeToSendMessage(member:["B"]): message aws_subscribe(mutations: ["sendMessage"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is not possible.
There's a similar question with good explanation in the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=286931&tstart=0)